# operation on dataframe with different index frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an hourly dataframe such as df1:

```
                  v1  v2
date
2015-01-01 0      20  25
2015-01-01 1      30  35
.
.
2015-02-01 0      45  55
2015-02-01 1      22  32
```

and I have a monthy datarfame such as df2:

```
                   v1     
date
2015-01-01         10    
2015-02-01         20
```

I would like to substract df2 from df1 based on the monthly value, result should be a dataframe with same granularity as df1 and such as:

```
                  v1  v2
date
2015-01-01 0      10  15
2015-01-01 1      20  25
.
.
2015-02-01 0      25  35
2015-02-01 1       2  12
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I merge dataframes and make subtraction

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

# create example data

d1 = '''date      v1  v2
2015-01-01 0      20  25
2015-01-01 1      30  35
2015-02-01 0      45  55
2015-02-01 1      22  32'''

d2 = '''date      v1     
2015-01-01         10    
2015-02-01         20'''

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO(d1), sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates='date')
df1.index = pd.to_datetime( df1.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H')

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO(d2), sep='\s+', parse_dates='date')

# start

df1['datetime'] = df1.index # to keep index in that column during merging

print '\n--- merge ---\n'

df = pd.merge( df1, df2, left_on=df1.index.date, right_on=df2.index.date)

print df

print '\n--- substract ---\n'

df['v1_x'] = df['v1_x'] - df['v1_y']
df['v2'] = df['v2'] - df['v1_y']

print df
```

result

```
--- merge ---

        key_0  v1_x  v2            datetime  v1_y
0  2015-01-01    20  25 2015-01-01 00:00:00    10
1  2015-01-01    30  35 2015-01-01 01:00:00    10
2  2015-02-01    45  55 2015-02-01 00:00:00    20
3  2015-02-01    22  32 2015-02-01 01:00:00    20

--- substract ---

        key_0  v1_x  v2            datetime  v1_y
0  2015-01-01    10  15 2015-01-01 00:00:00    10
1  2015-01-01    20  25 2015-01-01 01:00:00    10
2  2015-02-01    25  35 2015-02-01 00:00:00    20
3  2015-02-01     2  12 2015-02-01 01:00:00    20
```